# Can I get the root Pane from the primary stage using springboot-javafx-support?

Tags: java, spring-boot, javafx-8

I have a main page call `player.fxml` which is a BorderPane.Something like this

```
<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            fx:controller="cn.will.controller.PlayerController"
            fx:id="root"
            prefHeight="670.0" prefWidth="1020.0" stylesheets="@../css/player.css">
    <top>
        <fx:include source="titleBar.fxml"/>
    </top>
    <left>
        <fx:include source="userLeft.fxml"/>
    </left>
    <center>
        <fx:include source="albumDetail.fxml"/>
    </center>
    <bottom>
        <fx:include source="playBar.fxml"/>
    </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

In the Main.class I launch the app.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main extends AbstractJavaFxApplicationSupport implements ApplicationContextAware{

    private static BorderPane root;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launchApp(Main.class, PlayerView.class, new BlueprintSplashScreen(),args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        super.start(stage);
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image("img/music-icon32.png"));
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

   // ignore this. It's something I tried to meet my requirement.
   //I  try to use         
   //PlayerView view = applicationContext.getBean(PlayerView .class);
   //root = (BorderPane) view.getView();
   //but it throws NullPointerException dor applicationContext, it seems inject fail
    public ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }
}
```

I want to change the center content in the BorderPane dynamically.I really need to get this BorderPane so I can change it.
BTW,I also use Main.showView(xxx.class),but I just want to change the center.Not a whole stage.
Thanks a lot advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you post the controller referenced by that FXML: `fx:controller="cn.will.controller.PlayerController"`

I think you can get that BorderPane if you set up the annotate there by creating a field `@FXML BorderPane root;`.

---

I am not familiar with the `javafx-spring-support` library, but you can have fun with Spring and JavaFX without needing a seperate lib; the only dependency in my POM is `spring-boot-starter` *(from Spring Boot 2.0.0.M7)*:

**JAVA:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BootFXApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(BootFX.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    protected static Application bootFx() {

        // I declare this bean this way so I can use
        // the static instance stored when JavaFX
        // calls the no-arg 'BootFX' constructor
        // via reflection.

        if (BootFX.instance == null) {
            BootFX.instance = new BootFX();
        }

        return BootFX.instance;
    }

    public static class BootFX extends Application {

        private static BootFX instance;

        private ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;

        public BootFX() {
            BootFX.instance = this;
        }

        @Override
        public void init() throws Exception {

            String[] args = !isNull(getParameters()) ? 
                    getParameters().getRaw().toArray(new String[]{}) : new String[]{};

            applicationContext = new SpringApplicationBuilder(BootFXApplication.class)
                    .run(args);
        }

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            loader.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("fxml/main-pane.fxml").getURL());

            // This is the secret-sauce, have JavaFX get controllers from Spring
            loader.setControllerFactory(applicationContext::getBean);

            primaryStage.setTitle("Spring Boot + JavaFX");
            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(loader.load()));
            primaryStage.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void stop() throws Exception {
            SpringApplication.exit(applicationContext);
        }
    }


    @Bean
    public MainPaneController getMainController() {
        return new MainPaneController();
    }

}

// You would have this in a separate class, and could mark as
// @Component instead of declaring the MainPaneCtrl bean above
class MainPaneController {

    @FXML
    private BorderPane rootPane;

    public void initialize() {
        System.out.println(rootPane.toString());  // Mess around with your root pane here, i.e. set bindings
    }
}
```

**FXML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<BorderPane fx:id="rootPane" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
    fx:controller="com.hypersonicgoat.bootfx.MainPaneController"/>
```

I borrowed the concept from this talented developer; definitely check out his blog for more info: http://www.greggbolinger.com/let-spring-be-your-javafx-controller-factory

Comment: So appreciate it!This reminds me why I have to use springboot-javafx-support lib.Last night I like to try something like DI for controller,stage and spring occurs to me.I google it and found springboot-javafx-support lib.Now I wanna to ban it for a while.Maybe use it later.Thanks a lot for your contribution!

Comment: You are most welcome! 

The key thing I found really was the whole `fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory` thing - I think the DI setup helps a bunch once your app starts getting larger / more complex and you need to wire something like a common service into some JavaFX controller deep in your UI.

Answer (score 1):

I get more familiar with spring.By use springboot-javafx-support annotation @FXMLView the view already register to the spring bean factory.So when I want to use the view just use it.
use @Autowire  @Resources to inject the view to where u want.So you can get the view and invoke getView() method to get the root pane.